# Getting Error while running Mutation testing on Python code : AttributeError: 'MutationTestRunnerThread' object has no attribute 'isAlive'

Tags: python-3.x, mutation

I am working on Python programming Mutation testing using `Mut.py`. Unit testing is passed and when I run the Mutation testing on command line using the command, I am getting error like this.

```
C:\Users\pc\Desktop\My_Projects\Calculator01>mut.py --target simpleCalculator.py --unit-test test_simpleCalculator.py --runner pytest --coverage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\pc\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\mut.py", line 7, in <module>
    commandline.main(sys.argv)
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\mutpy\commandline.py", line 10, in main
    run_mutpy(parser)
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\mutpy\commandline.py", line 61, in run_mutpy
    mutation_controller = build_controller(cfg)
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\mutpy\commandline.py", line 73, in build_controller
    return controller.MutationController(
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\mutpy\controller.py", line 60, in __init__
    self.runner = runner_cls(self.test_loader, self.timeout_factor, self.stdout_manager, mutate_covered)
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\mutpy\test_runners\base.py", line 150, in __init__
    self.init_modules = self.find_init_modules()
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\mutpy\test_runners\base.py", line 209, in find_init_modules
    test_runner.terminate()
  File "c:\users\pc\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\mutpy\utils.py", line 357, in terminate
    if self.isAlive():
**AttributeError: 'MutationTestRunnerThread' object has no attribute 'isAlive'**
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently had the same issue, and here is a quick fix that worked for me:

- Open utils.py shown in the error message
- Go to the line "if self.isAlive():", shown in the error message
- Make the following change:
  `if self.isAlive():`
  becomes
  `if self.is_alive():`

My computer ran on Windows 10 with python 3.9.0, with mutpy 0.6.1.

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked partially, atleast recognised. Now I am getting different error. Sorry being stupid questions...since I am new to programming skills..C:\Users\pc\Desktop\My_Projects\Calculator01>mut.py --target simpleCalculator.py --unit-test test_simpleCalculator.py --runner pytest --coverage
[*] Start mutation process:
   - targets: simpleCalculator.py
   - tests: test_simpleCalculator.py
[*] Can't load module: test_simpleCalculator.py (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'test_simpleCalculator')

Comment: I tested the command you entered, and it worked fine for me. I would check if the names "simpleCalculator.py" and "test_simpleCalculator.py" are correct. If that does not work, I would verify that your command is run in the right directory.

Comment: Hey, Thanks.. I think it was to do with packages and module.. I fixed and it is working now.. Thanks a lot.. Now I am able to generate the report...

Comment: Do you also know how to generate the report summary on HTML.... Also I am working on testing it in Azure DevOps Pipeline.. is there any extension to report in Azure DevOps? Thanks a lot..

Comment: Not sure if it is what you asked, but you can use "coverage html" command to generate HTML test results. About Azure DevOps, I have no experience.